# Photoshop installation issaue-Unable to preserve original file

Tags: 14.04, apt, wine, adobe, photoshop

I am trying to install photoshop cs6 on ubuntu 14.04 using wine .
I am gettimg following error during installation-

```
Exit Code: 7
Please see specific errors below for troubleshooting. For example,  ERROR: DF024 ...


-------------------------------------- Summary --------------------------------------

 - 0 fatal error(s), 2 error(s) 



----------- Payload: Camera Profiles Installer 8.0.0.0 {56DCC6F4-322E-42DA-A5DA-26BAD28C1E10} -----------

ERROR: DF024: Unable to preserve original file at "C:\users\Public\Application Data\Adobe\CameraRaw\CameraProfiles\Index.dat" Error 0 (Seq 1)

----------- Payload: Adobe Photoshop CC 2014 Support 15.0.0.0 {18C53590-8A4E-44FF-B13D-74CB92FD6801} -----------

ERROR: DF024: Unable to preserve original file at "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CC 2014\32 bit Photoshop dlls\libifcoremd.dll" Error 0 (Seq 1)

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why am I getting this error and how can i resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can install this using playonlinux. To install playonlinux:

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Then, run playonlinux:

```
playonlinux &
```

click on install, wait for it to update, and then click on graphics.

Adobe photoshop cs6 should be one of the first ones listed. Click on it and then click install.